# complex json parsing in c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, c#-4.0, gridview

i am doing jSon parsing in C# (ASP).The problem is that when the JSON from klout is very complex, this is the response

```
{"myInfluencers":[{"entity":{"id":"851563","payload":{"kloutId":"851563","nick":"YouTube","score":{"score":100.0},"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":0.0,"weekChange":0.0,"monthChange":0.0}}}},{"entity":{"id":"100768049884337217","payload":{"kloutId":"100768049884337217","nick":"JessicaBiel","score":{"score":65.81697082519531}}}},{"entity":{"id":"879345","payload":{"kloutId":"879345","nick":"brokemogul","score":{"score":65.55970764160156},"scoreDeltas":{"dayChange":-0.2452850341796875,"weekChange":-0.6857528686523438,"monthChange":-2.5359420776367188}}}},{"entity":{"id":"25332752669424610","payload":{"kloutId":"25332752669424610","nick":"EsteeStanley","score":{"score":64.1717529296875}}}},{"entity":{"id":"28710452389286536","payload":{"kloutId":"28710452389286536","nick":"robknox_ys","score":{"score":60.353816986083984}}}}],"myInfluencees":[{"entity":{"id":"98516250154496343","payload":{"kloutId":"98516250154496343","nick":"LYNASXD","score":{"score":14.632675170898438}}}},{"entity":{"id":"42784201225370648","payload":{"kloutId":"42784201225370648","nick":"JenThackray","score":{"score":14.392120361328125}}}},{"entity":{"id":"52635827290381715","payload":{"kloutId":"52635827290381715","nick":"JTChile","score":{"score":13.279963493347168}}}},{"entity":{"id":"60235650788244656","payload":{"kloutId":"60235650788244656","nick":"upallnight356","score":{"score":11.61323070526123}}}},{"entity":{"id":"97108875505882083","payload":{"kloutId":"97108875505882083","nick":"anisahmutiahna","score":{"score":10.5490140914917}}}}],"myInfluencersCount":14,"myInfluenceesCount":25}
```

The classes generated are as follows

```
public class Score
{
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class ScoreDeltas
{
    public double dayChange { get; set; }
    public double weekChange { get; set; }
    public double monthChange { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public string kloutId { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
    public Score score { get; set; }
    public ScoreDeltas scoreDeltas { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
}

public class MyInfluencer
{
    public Entity entity { get; set; }
}

public class Score2
{
    public double score { get; set; }
}

public class Payload2
{
    public string kloutId { get; set; }
    public string nick { get; set; }
    public Score2 score { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Payload2 payload { get; set; }
}

public class MyInfluencee
{
    public Entity2 entity { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<MyInfluencer> myInfluencers { get; set; }
    public List<MyInfluencee> myInfluencees { get; set; }
    public int myInfluencersCount { get; set; }
    public int myInfluenceesCount { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind the results with a gridview.Even if i use JSON.NET then we can't extract the things one by one.I used `deserialize` before but here the scenerio is too nested.
Anyone who can help me to find a good way to solve this.Thank you in meekness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I found was to create the small classes

- Using JSON.NET

  JObject o = JObject.Parse(text_klout);
                       influencee = o.SelectToken("myInfluencees").ToString();
                       influencer = o.SelectToken("myInfluencers").ToString();
  Seperate them
  Then iterate over each other using

  JavaScriptSerializer _jsserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  it works...

Answer (score 2):

Your json is indeed deeply nested. Instead of declaring a lot of tiny classes I would go this way:

```
var jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var myInfluencers = jobj["myInfluencers"]
                        .Children()
                        .Select(x => (dynamic)x["entity"])
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            id = x.id.ToString(),
                            kloutId = x.payload.kloutId.ToString(),
                            nick = x.payload.nick.ToString(),
                            score = x.payload.score.score.ToString(),
                        })
                        .ToArray();
```

`myInfluencees` has the same structure with `myInfluencers`

Even if you don't want to use anonymous classes, you don't need a class more than this

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string id;
    public string kloutId; 
    public string nick; 
    public string score; 
    //a few fields more??
 }
```

Comment: whats the use of Dummy Class here?

Comment: You may want to use it as `Select(x => new DummyClass` instead of anonymous class.

Comment: Thanks for your response..i am checking it and get back to you

Comment: it's not working as it point out errors at  x=> new.. "May be missing refernce to Microsft.CSharp",but I have included the refernce.It says that value for dunamic will be resolved at run time

Comment: Are you using .net 4.0? I have never posted a code before testing it.

Comment: Yes I am using 4.0,please help me with this,this is the most important task for me...